# Find source of Spotlight Dictionary result

Tags: macos, catalina, spotlight, dictionary

When we look up the meaning of any word through Spotlight:

[image]

There is no 'source' information.

[image: Find]

Even the Dictionary.app, which Spotlight uses, does not show the source.

The best I can find so far is to disable / enable different Dictionaries in Dictionary.app's Preferences, until the definition disappears / changes, to figure out from what dictionary the meaning is from.

How can I see where the definition comes from without this pain?

Comment: I don’t understand from your question what the actual problem is. Do you have a screenshot that shows the expected result and one that shows the actual result?

Comment: @daneb - The Dictionary app allows us to add many "source" dictionary, thesaurus, etc. When a search in Dictionary displays a result, OP wants to know from which source it is. (See my answer for more info).

Comment: You must be a mind-reading ninja. Your answer makes sense but I’m still not convinced that is the OPs question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dictionary` app does tell you the source, though it is not intuitive. When you add a new "*source*" through Dictionary's **Preferences**, the Dictionary app adds a ***tab button*** for it on the top.

- Example 1 - *Oxford Dictionary*:

[image: Dictionary screenshot - Oxford]

- Example 2 - *Apple Dictionary*:

[image: Dictionary screenshot - Apple]

---

When a search result is displayed in Dictionary, the ***tab button*** name highlights the source from which it found the result.

---

Sometimes, the ***tab button*** names are not helpful. For such cases, you can rename it to what you want:

- Right-click the ***tab name***, and click on ***Edit Label***:

[image: Dictionary screenshot - Renaming a tab button]

- Type the new name, and click ***OK***.

[image: Dictionary screenshot - Renaming a tab button]

- The tab button will now be renamed:

[image: Dictionary screenshot - Renaming a tab button]